# I can't iterate over a javascript array

Tags: javascript

I am going crazy here, I have an associative array as seen below which is defined after the page finishes loading. However `Array.forEach` is returning `undefined` and I have no idea why. The array is most definitely populated during the loop. Can anyone give me any ideas? Also doesn't work with JQuery's `$.each`

[image]

Comment: pictures don't help. add your actual code

Comment: adding my code would be a bit difficult because it reads json with ajax to populate members array. But I feel that part is not necessary, and there is no other code yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays are usually a mapping of *index* (integer from 0 to 2<sup>32</sup> − 2, inclusive) to *value*. In your case you've treated the array as a dictionary e.g. *key* (string) to *value*.

You've probably done something like this:

```js
members = new Array();
members['animerox1213'] = 'Ashima';
```

JavaScript allows this, after all it is still an object:

```js
typeof members === 'object'
```

But instead of adding a value to the array, you've actually set a non-numeric property on the object called `animerox1213`. That is not how an array should be used and we can observe this by checking the size:

```js
members.length === 0;
```

Consequently, `forEach` does *not* do anything as it considers it an empty array.

That said, it is enumerable with [`for`…`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) as it's still just an object (with enumerable properties):

```js
for (m in members) {
  console.log(m, members[m]);
}
```

Consider using just an object e.g. `members = {}` or [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Note especially the section [Objects vs. Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps).

Comment: When I declared the `members` variable, I wrote `members = new Array()` and then did `members[a] = b;` Why did this become an Object?

Comment: js is untyped.  members was an array and then you made it an associative array - or dictionary.  check https://flexiple.com/javascript/associative-array-javascript/

Comment: `typeof members === 'object'` would also be the case if `members` _was_ an array. This isn’t a test for arrays. Arrays _are_ objects; they can contain any key you want, but if they contain something other than numeric keys, you’re just misusing arrays. JS is definitely not untyped.

Comment: @SebastianSimon yes you're right, I'm working on an edit to address that. I was too hasty in my answer

Comment: @SebastianSimon I'm failing to understand why you said *"JS is definitely not untyped"*.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Because [DCR’s claim that _“js is untyped”_](/questions/74341238/i-cant-iterate-over-a-javascript-array#comment131243226_74341266) is incorrect. Every value in the language is of exactly one type, of [the possible (currently 8) types](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types).

Comment: @SebastianSimon But that's correct, dynamically typed (which JS is) can be called "untyped". Even the JS creator says that: https://twitter.com/brendaneich/status/166310376340848643

Comment: @GerardoFurtado In that case, the term “untyped” has an unfortunate ambiguity, so the term is perhaps best avoided… Also, even if this just means that types are dynamic, then assigning a non-numeric property to an Array still doesn’t magically _change_ its type. It still remains an Object. And it still remains an Array.

Comment: By the way, just to add another bit of terminology: arrays are [indexed collections](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-indexed-collections) whereas plain objects are [keyed collections](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-keyed-collections).